# Endless Loop with localhost and not with domain

Tags: php, infinite-loop

A while ago I was working on a website that I was making for my self (not to publish it).

Now I want to continue it, but what I get when I go to:

> localhost/Login/index.php

it just redirects to:

> localhost/Login/logout.php

And the page says it is an endless loop.

Now, I also tried it on domain:

> .tk/Login/index.php

and things work as expected.

Do you guys have any suggestion what kind of problem this is?

Comment: login=map name ? can you please explain this ?

Comment: Sorry I will delete that. its just localhost/Login/index.php

Comment: please paste your index.php code in the question.

Comment: Raheel Khan it works now:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Srry guys, IDK what the problem was i didnt changed anything in my code.
But it works now!

I think there was something with the COOKIE Settings!

Comment: You should keep digging though. This have now been a issue once and will properly come back if you do not find it. As you said yourself, it was properly something with the cookie settings. That would be a good place to start digging :D

Comment: @AnotherGuy Ye for the next I can find the bug I hope!